# Combination during time period

Tags: permutations, combinations

There is a workforce who can handle $3$ products and the $3$ products have different execution times: $1h$, $2h$, $4h$.
How do I calculate all possible combinations this workforce may create between $8$ AM and $12$ AM ? I explain:

1. $1h$, $1h$, $1h$, $1h$
2. $1h$, $1h$, $2h$
3. $1h$, $2h$, $1h$
4. $2h$, $1h$, $1h$
5. $2h$, $2h$
6. $4h$

I need a formula as the number of products may be more than $3$ and the time slot may also vary.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Do you count combinations *2.*, *3.*, and *4.* as different ones? In this case, what you're looking for is rather the number of arrangments

Comment: I can think of an algorithmic way to calculate every possible arrangment, but no idea on how to count them without calculating. Basically, it's the [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: @ BusyAnt : 2. 3. 4. are different, so the number of arrangements is needed...
What will be the algorithme?

Comment: Well I can't say I would explain it very well, and the Wiki page is not bad... In short your problem is known as follows : *I've got a knapsack, which weight-capacity is limited, and some objects that have a certain mass. What are the combinations of objects I can take, and more specifically, which one is the best?* FIY, there is a 1-Million-dollar bounty if you can solve this in polynomial time ;)

Comment: ;) will give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the Knapsack Problem.

*(see comments for precisions)*